# Ringtone volume decreases after silenting and unsilenting my HTC Desire X

Tags: settings, volume-control, ringtone, htc-desire-x

It's that clear as Title says.

1. I can see that current `Ringtone and Notification` volume is at the highest level.
2. I now put my phone in silence mode and deselected Silent (I selected it using maximizing the top nav(?) bar, and activating silent (and then deactivating silent mode) from there.
3. Now I go back to `Settings` and see that the Volume is very low (about 10% as it looks).

---

I want my settings back after disabling Silent mode and going Normal.

Environment:

- Phone: HTC Desire X Dual Sim
- Android Version: 4.1.1
- Kernel Version: 3.4.0-ge410a46
- Software number: 1.0.0. Desire X

I can also give the whole information in `Settings` -> `About` -> `Software Information` if they are not enough.

Comment: Can you provide more information about which phone you are using, and which version of Android?

Comment: Don't you have an update to 4.1.2 available? I don't know if the Desire X have it, but in general, every device running Jelly Bean 4.1 are updated to 4.1.2...

Comment: It's less than a week that I have bought my new phone and I haven't even rooted it. I haven't also updated to 4.1.2 myself. The information was gathered from `Settings` -> `About` -> `Software Information`.